# TortoiseGit 1.7.8: "Couldn't load this key" on "sync" or "pull"?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When I try to use "Git Sync" and then "Pull" I get the error:

> Couldn't load this key (unable to open file)

It then tries to proceed with the pull and I get this error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

This has happened only since I upgraded to 1.7.8.0.  It was all working just fine before.  I can successefully pull using gitbash so I know I can connect.

I am not sure what changed, or what I can do to fix it.  Please help!

**ADDITIONAL STEPS**

I went to the the GIT folder and used gitbash to check git remote -v and received:
.puttykeyfile
origin git@github.com:{name}/{repository}.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:{name}/{repository}.git (push)

I think that is correct.

I checked the putty key settings in tortoisegit.  I have two entries:

1. .puttykeyfile - which just has .puttykeyfile in Remote
2. origin - this appears to have all the correct information in Remote, URL and Putty
   Key

When I load the key in PuTTYGen it has the ssh-rsa 1024... key fingerprint.

pageant.exe was running, but isn't now, but it still doesn't work

When it was working before, I had on git folder in the same folder as my key.  Now I have 3, but none of them work and it doesn't seem to work if I create a new git folder with a single repository and key.  I don't know if it affects the results, but wanted to share that just in case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That happens when you can not authenticate to the remote server, for some reason your keys are not found. You installed a new version of tortoiseGit. Were your keys inside that folder? maybe they were removed when you installed the new version.

Check the remotes are configured in your Git repository

```
git remote -v
```

If they are correct, and you still have your keys, try to add them again to the tortoise settings

TortoiseGit Settings - Git - Remote - Putty key

If you need help to convert your rsa keys (used to authenticate with) to putty format:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/

Also check that pageant.exe is not running (you can check that in the systry), it could be causing problems if the loaded key is not found

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Apparently a new key was created and I hadn't loaded the new key to the server.

Answer (score 3):

That happened when reinstall my system. After I deployed the tortoisGit, it showed me the tips when I used 'Git pull' or other code.
[erro tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq9P2.png)

Then I searched this issue, but it did not resole my problem. Fortunately, I recognised that whether it was the problem of the old configuration? So, I opened the 'config' file of my project, deleted the 'puttykeyfile' line.

...!

Resolved!

Hoping to help you!

ps: project dictionary -> .git -> config -> puttykeyfile

Comment: yes I have the same problem because I copied repositories from old pc to new pc, I removed the line of putty file and now it's ok!